# Remove duplicate reverse pairs

Tags: sql

I am making a table of all product SKUs (fj1_sku column) paired with the product SKU of a second product which is a close substitute to that product (fj2_sku column) based on a range of criteria.  To get the main matrix I have done a cross join of the final_join table with itself.

I cannot figure out how to remove the mirror duplicate pairs in the resulting table:

| fj1_sku | fj2_sku |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 |
| 11 | 10 |

i.e. I only want one row with the pair 11 & 10.

I have tried a number of solutions found on this platform, but do not want to use a "select distinct" because I need many variables that I cannot use a distinct with.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
select 
  fj1.sku as fj1_sku,
  fj2.sku as fj2_sku,
  fj1.name as fj1_name,
  fj2.name as fj2_name,
  fj1.brand as fj1_brand,
  fj2.brand as fj2_brand
from final_join as fj1
cross join final_join as fj2
where (fj1.sku <> fj2.sku) and (fj1.brand <> fj2.brand)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicates for *all* pairs, then you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where fj1_sku < fj2_sku;
```

If not, you can use be more selective:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.fj1_sku < t.fj2_sku or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.fj1_sku = t.fj2_sku and
                        t2.fj2_sku = t.fj1_sku
                 );
```

You can also incorporate similar logic into a `delete`, if you actually want to change the table.